# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn’t communicate with the NVIDIA driver

Tags: nvidia, cuda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

wsl 4.19.121
ubuntu 18.04
cuda-toolkit 11.0
nvidia driver: 460.15

I’ve followed the steps in this tutorial
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html
But when I finished and called ‘nvidia-smi’. I got the following error:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver.
Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```